# Find path on the Graph. Which can help me by visiting all the Points and calculate distance as well

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I am not able to find the Path which should cover all my vertices and edges. Also we can visit the Vertiex again.

I am able to find the path from one point to another but that does not cover all the points.

```
 import networkx as nx
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 class Node:
     def addNode(self,graph,name,o_time,c_time):
         graph.add_node(name,open_time=o_time,close_time=c_time)

     def updateNode(self,graph,name,o_time,c_time):
         if name in graph:
             attrs = {name:{'open_time': o_time, 'close_time': c_time}}
             nx.set_node_attributes(graph, attrs)

 class Edge(Node):
     def addEdge(self,graph,edge1,edge2,weight):
         if edge1 not in graph:
             Node.addNode(self,graph,edge1,'None','None')
         if edge2 not in graph:
             Node.addNode(self,graph,edge2,'None','None')

         graph.add_edge(edge1,edge2,weight=weight)

 G = nx.Graph()
 d = Node()
 edge = Edge()

 d.addNode(G,'Ngurah Rai International Airport','8:00Am','8:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Tanah Lot Temple','8:00Am','8:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Mt Batur','9:00Am','9:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Uluwatu Temple','10:00Am','10:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Sacred Monkey Forest Sanctuary','10:00Am','10:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Agung Rai Museum of Art','10:00Am','10:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Tegallalang Rice Terrace','10:00Am','10:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Waterbom Bali Indonesia','10:00Am','10:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Ulun Danu Beratan Temple','10:00Am','10:00Pm')
 d.addNode(G,'Kuta Beach','10:00Am','10:00Pm')

 edge.addEdge(G,'Ngurah Rai International Airport','Kuta Beach',20)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Ngurah Rai International Airport','Uluwatu Temple',50)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Kuta Beach','Tanah Lot Temple',70)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Sacred Monkey Forest Sanctuary','Agung Rai Museum of Art',20)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Ngurah Rai International Airport','Agung Rai Museum of Art',100)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Agung Rai Museum of Art','Tegallalang Rice Terrace',60)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Sacred Monkey Forest Sanctuary','Tegallalang Rice Terrace',50)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Tegallalang Rice Terrace','Mt Batur',100)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Ngurah Rai International Airport','Waterbom Bali Indonesia',10)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Waterbom Bali Indonesia','Kuta Beach',10)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Tanah Lot Temple','Ulun Danu Beratan Temple',70)
 edge.addEdge(G,'Kuta Beach','Ulun Danu Beratan Temple',100)

 d.updateNode(G,'Los','10:00Am','10:00Pm')

 start = 'Ngurah Rai International Airport'
 for node in G.nodes():
     for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=start, target=node):
         if(len(path) >= 5):
             print(path)
             print(str( nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=start, target=node, weight='weight') ) + 'Km')

 nx.draw(G,arrows=True,with_labels=True)
 plt.savefig("simple_path.png") # save as png
 plt.show()
```

Current Output is

> ```
> 'Ngurah Rai International Airport', 'Waterbom Bali Indonesia', 'Kuta Beach', 'Ulun Danu Beratan Temple', 'Tanah Lot Temple'
> 90Km
> 'Ngurah Rai International Airport', 'Agung Rai Museum of Art', 'Sacred Monkey Forest Sanctuary', 'Tegallalang Rice Terrace', 'Mt Batur'
> 260Km
> 'Ngurah Rai International Airport', 'Waterbom Bali Indonesia', 'Kuta Beach', 'Tanah Lot Temple', 'Ulun Danu Beratan Temple'
> 120Km
> ```

I am expecting output as

> ```
> 'Ngurah Rai International Airport', 'Waterbom Bali Indonesia', 'Kuta Beach', 'Ulun Danu Beratan Temple', 'Tanah Lot Temple', 'Kuta Beach', 'Ngurah Rai International Airport', 'Ulluwalu Temple', 'Ngurah Rai International Airport', 'Agung Rai Museum of Art', 'Sacred Monkey Forest Sanctuary', 'Tegallalang Rice Terrace', 'Mt Batur'
> ```

Comment: I have edited this a bit to make the formatting better.  Please check that I have done it all correctly.

Comment: Your problem statement says you are looking for a path that goes through every node, and that the path is allowed to revisit any node.  But you are calculating all **simple** paths from the start (so they don't revisit any node).  Your approach won't find the output you're after because `path` is a **simple** path.  Additionally when you find a path (named `path`) of at least 5 nodes, you print out `path` and then you print out the shortest path length from the start to the given node, rather than the length of  `path`.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want a path that covers every edge.  I will assume you want it to cover every edge exactly once.

Then you are looking for an Eulerian circuit.  (which, by the way exists if and only if the graph is connected and all nodes have even degree).

Use  `nx.eulerian_circuit(G, source=Ngurah Rai International Airport')`.  The documentation is [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_circuit.html#networkx.algorithms.euler.eulerian_circuit).

Comment: Thanks Joel. I did check that But I am looking to Explore all the Vertices at one go. It doesn't matter if the Edge repeats again.

Comment: Do you want it to go through all vertices **and** all edges at least once?  Or just all vertices at least once?

Comment: All the edges atleast once.

Comment: There will be many such paths.  Are you after the shortest?  Or is any path good enough?